# Why $area gave me a wrong value QGIS 2.99?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.18, qgis-3

I want to calculate the area with $area function in QGIS 2.99 but the operation gave me a wrong value.

Here is a picture comparing the results between QGIS 2.99 and QGIS  2.18. The right side is QGIS 2.18 and its OK, I compare the result with ArcGIS.

[image]

Here are the projection properties from each one.

QGIS 2.99

[image]

QGIS 2.18
[image]

Comment: You need to also show your project properties screen - specifically the ellipsoid settings.

Comment: Sorry - that's not what I meant. I mean the first tab in "Project Properties", which shows the project ellipsoid setting.

Comment: ndawson. I changed the pictures. But I saw something. When in QGIS2.99 I select the buttom "Ninguna proyección" it works fine and give the right value. ¿Do you know why?

Comment: Sorry - still giving the wrong picture. I need the first tab: "General"

Comment: ndawson, Thanks a lot!! I know now why it's happen. I put the pictures. The ellipsoid was different in QGIS 2.99.  Again Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ManuelAlejandro Please post the solution as an answer. (It is ok to answer your own questions.) This way, the system will recognize that the issue has been answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ndawson show me why the $area function give different values.

We have to have the same ellipsoid setting, it must be configured in QGIS2.99.

This picture show where we have to set the ellipsoid.

[image]

In my case I selected "None/Planimetric" and it worked.